# Проблемы с содержимым модальных окон настройки отслеживания обычных значков и значков меток

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, дизайн

Внутри своего профиля на вкладке "Активность" есть возможность настроить отслеживание обычных значков и значков меток.

[image: Расположение кнопки вызова модального окна настройки отслеживания обычных значков]

Внутри этих модальных окон есть несколько проблем:

- Не используются существующие переводы строк для "Select your next badge", "recommended" и "Search for a badge...". На transifex они точно переведены и перевод отмечен как используемый.
- Проблемы с z-index и overflow у блока `.all-badge-progress`. Содержимое дочерних блоков `.badge-progress` вываливается за его нижнюю границу.

[image: Демонстрация глюков модального окна 1]

---

- Содержимое `.badge-description` вываливается за пределы родительского блока `.badge-progress` из-за отсутствия overflow и жестко заданной высоты последнего.

[image: Демонстрация глюков модального окна 2]

---

- Если долистать до нижней границы модального окна, то можно заметить, что полоса прокрутки тоже вываливается за его границы.

[image: Демонстрация глюков модального окна 3]

---

- В модальном окне настроек отслеживания *значков меток* почему-то используются строки для модального окна настроек отслеживания *обычных значков*, хотя, судя по содержимому подсказки для кнопки вызова модальных окон, это разные вещи.
- Нет отступа от вкладок до строки поиска. Особенно это хорошо заметно на активной вкладке (на скриншоте "Бронзовые").
- В данном модальном окне наблюдаются все те же проблемы с z-index и overflow, что и у модального окна настроек отслеживания обычных значков.

[image: Демонстрация глюков модального окна 4]

---

Тестировал в Chrome, но думаю, что проблема с версткой будет и в других браузерах.

Comment: Угу. То же в FF.

Comment: К сожалению, еще не все строки получили вторую галку (проверку). Прямо сейчас просматриваем. Скорее всего, решим в течении двух трех недель. Сразу после просмотра всех строк вернемся к проблеме сломанной верскти.

Comment: Еще раз внимательно прошелся по ошибкам: скорее всего все проблемы вызваны тем, что у нас длинные названия табов, из за чего строка поиска переходит на след. строчку. Что-то мне подсказывает, коллеги первым делам будут просить уменьшить длину названий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Будет исправлено в следующем деплое.